# A question about $\log_{10} ⁡(x) = k\ln⁡x $

Tags: logarithms

I need help on this question:

> $\log_{10} ⁡(x) = k\ln⁡x $
>
> By raising $10$ to the power of both sides, show that $k= \frac1{\ln⁡10}$ .

I have absolutely no clue on how to start.

Comment: What is troubling you about this question?

Comment: Also, please use MathJax to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What have you done so far? We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions but people will be more willing to help you out if they can see you have put some effort in yourself first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $10^{\log_{10}(x)}= x$

What is $10^{k\ln(x)}$? 
Write $10=e^{\ln(10)}$, then we get $(e^{\ln(10)})^{k \ln(x)} = e^{\ln(x) k \ln(10)}= (e^{\ln(x)})^{k \ln(10)}= x^{k \ln(10)}$, which thus equals $x=x^1$, hence $k\ln(10)=1$ etc..

Comment: I had absoltuely no clue how to start.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get confused about these logarithm questions - which way round the logs are and whether to divide or multiply.

If in doubt, I generally go back to powers.

So suppose $x=10^a$ and $10=e^b$ then $x=(e^b)^a=e^{ab}$

Then I can take logarithms and see what is going on in that language.